# what stops communication outside android app to app engine w/auth?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

if this is a duplicate, sorry i tried looking though

ive read the docs at google about authentication options for app engine

if im using just simple POST 'protocol' between android and gae,

i can obviously authenticate my POST's to make sure they came from 'account holders'

but what stops someone signing up, logging in or sending posts outside my app ?

is there some seed/signature in my android app that 'says', "hey this is communication coming specifically from my android app" ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is not real way to stop someone from impersonating your client, almost every digital method that you can think of cab be replicated to other digital device.

The question that you need to ask yourself is why do you care that the client is not a "real" client.

Comment: well because they can then 'spoof' game data to my server to make it seem like they are doing things they are not ?